# What's the difference between non-static initializer block of non-static variable and regular initialization in java

Tags: java, static

What is the diffirence between initialization :
1)int i = 47 ;
or
2)int i ;
{i = 47; }
in which cases we need 1st or 2nd ?

```
public class Bath {
  private String // Initializing at point of definition:
    s1 = "Happy",
    s2 = "Happy",
    s3, s4;
  private Soap castile;
  int i;
  private float toy;
  public Bath() {
    System.out.println("Inside Bath()");
    s3 = "Joy";
    toy = 3.14f;
    castile = new Soap();
  }
  // Instance initialization:
  { i = 47; }
 }
```

Comment: Your question title should be about instance initialization blocks, not about static initialization blocks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a static initializer block for an instance variable. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Instance initialization allows you to do some pre-calculations before finally assigning a value to an instance variable. For example:

```
public class Bath {
  private String // Initializing at point of definition:
    s1 = "Happy",
    s2 = "Happy",
    s3, s4;
  private Soap castile;
  int i;
  private float toy;

  public Bath() {
    System.out.println("Inside Bath()");
    s3 = "Joy";
    toy = 3.14f;
    castile = new Soap();
  }

  // Instance initialization:
  { 
    // some pre-calculations
    int sum = 2*3 + 5*5 + 5;
    int sum2 = 2*4 + 3;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      sum2 += i;
    }

    // assign
    i = sum + sum2; 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

`int i = 47;` means you are declaring and initializing at the same time but
`int i;` and `{ i = 47;}` means you are declaring and instance initializing separately.
Instance initialization is used whenever its class object is created and to do some predefined calculations and operations before final initialization .

Comment: `Instance initalization is used whenever its class object is created': no it isn't, and it does not precede 'final initialization'.